# How can I access images from qrc.py into reportlab?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, reportlab, qresource

I have converted "image_fonts.qrc" into image_fonts_rc.py file. It has one image named as "image.png"

How can I use an image into reportlab PDF in Python from qrc.py file.

#### File *image_fonts.qrc*

```xml
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="image_fonts">
    <file>image.png</file>
    <file>logo.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

```py
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/image_fonts/logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
```

I used above the lines, but I get an error. Please find the below error.

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not QIcon

Minimal Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, PageTemplate, TableStyle, Paragraph, Image, Spacer, Frame, Paragraph, Flowable
import image_fonts_rc


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test_images.ui", self)
        self.show()

        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/image_fonts/logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

        doc = SimpleDocTemplate("images.pdf", pagesize=A4, rightMargin=40, leftMargin=40, topMargin=20, bottomMargin=20, title ="Images")

        width, height = A4
        document = []

        logo = icon
        imgw = imgh = 80
        im = (Image(logo, width=imgw, height=imgh))

        document.append(im)

        doc.build(document)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre], in the code you provide there is no line on reportlab so I am not able to understand the error message you indicate.

Comment: Just I have updated my Question with minimal Example. Please find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use QPixmap or QIcon but you must get the bytes from the image as in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64449003/6622587):

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image

import image_fonts_rc


def convert_qrc_to_bytesio(filename):
    file = QtCore.QFile(filename)
    if not file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
        raise RuntimeError(file.errorString())
        return
    f = BytesIO(file.readAll().data())
    return f


doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
    "images.pdf",
    pagesize=A4,
    rightMargin=40,
    leftMargin=40,
    topMargin=20,
    bottomMargin=20,
    title="Images",
)

width, height = A4
document = []

logo = convert_qrc_to_bytesio(":/image_fonts/logo.png")
imgw = imgh = 80
im = Image(logo, width=imgw, height=imgh)

document.append(im)

doc.build(document)
```

Comment: Its Working Perfect.